# retrieve claims coming from azure ad b2c login using node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD B2C to perform my authentication. After successfully login, I see in the browser something like:

localhost:3000/#id_token=eyJ0elll...

I am wondering how to retrieve that token in my Nodejs backend

Comment: Hi C.Shi Are you developing a JavaScript single-page app or a Node.js web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you followed the tutorial `Azure Active Directory B2C: Web sign-in with OpenID Connect` to send authentication request of url like `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?.....` and get a `30x` response to redirect to the location `localhost:3000/#id_token=eyJ0elll...&code=AwABAAAA...&state=arb....` in browser. And now, you want to realize it in NodeJS without browser.

Here is my simple code using [`request/request`](https://github.com/request/request).

```
const request = require('request');
var url = require("url");
var querystring = require("querystring");
var authorize_uri = 'https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?.....';
request(authorize_uri, function (error, response, body) {
    var href = response.request.href; // get localhost:3000/#id_token=eyJ0elll...&code=AwABAAAA...&state=arb....
    var hash = url.parse(href).hash; // get #id_token=eyJ0elll...&code=AwABAAAA...&state=arb....
    //var hash = response.request.uri.hash; // or directly get #id_token=eyJ0elll...&code=AwABAAAA...&state=arb....
    var id_token = querystring.parse(hash)['#id_token'];
    console.log(id_token);
});
```